# Problem in accessing elements from google HashMultimap

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I am using below code to get & process value from google HashMultimap

```
    HashMultimap hmm = new HashMultimap();
    HashMultimap hmm2 = new HashMultimap();
    Element ele;
:
    hmm2.put("name","Amit");
    hmm.put("Amit",ele);
    hmm.put("rohit",hmm2);
 :   
    Iterator itr =  hmm.keys().iterator();
    String ky = (String) itr.next();
    System.out.println(hmm.get(ky));
    ky = (String) itr.next();
    System.out.println(hmm.get(ky));
```

In above code, if map element(or entry) is Element type then i want to do some operation. If it is HashMultimap type then do some other operation. How can i check and pass the object to another function.

Comment: are you living in Java 1.4 world? Use generic!

Comment: this is my project limitation. i cant do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a `HashMultimap` which is also a `SetMultimap`, when you call `hmm.get(ky)` the value returned is going to be a `Set` of all the values for that key.  You should then be able to iterate through each of the values in the `Set` and use `instanceof` on those values.  If there are not going to be multiple values for each key, you shouldn't be using a `Multimap` to begin with and should just use normal `HashMap`.

```
    HashMultimap hmm = HashMultimap.create();
    HashMultimap hmm2 = HashMultimap.create();
    Element ele = new Element();
    hmm2.put("name", "Amit");
    hmm.put("Amit", ele);
    hmm.put("rohit", hmm2);
    Iterator itr = hmm.keys().iterator();
    String ky = (String) itr.next();

    Set elements = hmm.get(ky);
    Iterator elementsItr = elements.iterator();
    Object val = elementsItr.next();
    if (val instanceof Element) {
        doElementStuff((Element) val);
    }

    ky = (String) itr.next();
    elements = hmm.get(ky);
    elementsItr = elements.iterator();
    val = elementsItr.next();
    if (val instanceof Element) {
        doElementStuff((Element) val);
    }
```

The key point is that calling `get()` on a `HashMultimap` returns a `Set` of values and not a single value.

Comment: Are you talking to access value  like `SetMultimap o = (SetMultimap) hmm.get(ky);`. It gives runtime error.

Comment: Updated answer to try and clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

Use the instanceof keyword.

Like so:
`if (item instanceof Element) //Do things`

Comment: If you asking to me then it is complete code. if you are asking to @Woot4Moo then i suppose he is taking item of Object type